# Formatar números decimais no Google Chart

Tags: jquery, google-charts

Estou usando o Google Chart para trazer valores decimais do PHP. A estrutura está da seguinte forma:

PHP

```
<?php
$visualizarChartPagos = $metodos->visualizarPagosChart(date("Y"));
$valor = $visualizarChartPagos[7];
?>
```

Como resultado:

> 4230.00

E no chart:

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Mês', 'Pagos', 'Pendentes'],
          ['Jan',  <?php echo $valor; ?>, 400],
          ['Fev',  1170,      460],
          ['Mar',  660,       1120],
          ['Abr',  332,       120],
          ['Mai',  120,       343],
          ['Jun',  324,       545],
          ['Jul',  545,       1243],
          ['Ago',  6534,       5566],
          ['Set',  623,       2221],
          ['Out',  545,       221],
          ['Nov',  667,       326],
          ['Dez',  1030,      540]
        ]);
```

Quando visualizo no chart, aparece dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que aparece **4,230**. Como eu faria para que a visualização fique dessa forma **4.230,00**? Tentei usar o **number_format()** do PHP, mas não aceitou.

Tentei fazer dessa forma, mas não funcionou:

```
var options = {
          title: 'Dados gráficos do ano de <?php echo date("Y"); ?>',
          hAxis: {format:'##.###,##', title: 'Ano: <?php echo date("Y"); ?>',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0},
          vAxis: {format:'0.00'}
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
              decimalSymbol: ',',
              groupingSymbol: '.',
              prefix: 'R$ '
        });
// Estou aplicando para as colunas 2 e 3
formatter.format(data, 1);
formatter.format(data, 2);
```